# Can I create a private social network with Diaspora?

Tags: diaspora

I'd like to have a private social network for my business.

Is this possible with Diaspora?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Diaspora, but you can create one with [Ning](http://www.ning.com/).

Comment: Please do note Ning is proprietary. So, not a valid alternative to open source software Diaspora*